# Pass bash variable into python file

Tags: linux, bash, python

I have a Python script that I want to pass a bash variable to.

bash.sh

```
while read -r db
do
Printf  "%s\n" ${db} "Found"
done < path/to/file.txt
```

output: db1
        db2
        db3

file.txt

```
db1
db2
db3
```

python.py

```
print(${db},+"_tables.replicate.fix")
```

I need an output of  : db1
                      db2
                      db3

How can the python file know what the db variable holds in the bash file?

Comment: I see no connection here between Bash script and Python script. Guessing that it would be called after the `printf` line in Bash?

Comment: are you asking how to write to a file in Bash then read from that same file in Python?

Comment: OP is possibly asking how to do this within a bash heredoc. or, maybe how to use the export option to export the variable and then source later from a script.

Comment: ... or perhaps they are asking how to use `sys.argv`?

Comment: @Kwesi Gene, unclear what you are asking; Please, provide more details

Comment: The $db variable in the .sh file returns db1, db2,db3. I want to use the same variable "$db" in the python file to return the same output. Not sure how to make the two scripts talk together

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74246/117549 might help -- export the variable then use os.environ; or use https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237443/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-into-a-python-script?rq=1 and pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to "export" the shell `db` variable to a program that the script runs would be to pass it as an argument, and then the python command can read it from `sys.argv`.

It might look like this:

```
while IFS= read -r db
do
printf  "%s\n" "${db} Found"
python -c 'import sys; print("db: %s" % sys.argv[1])' "$db"
done < path/to/file.txt
```