# Use bash variable in python

Tags: linux, bash, python

How can I call use a variable in bash and use the same variable in python. There are two separate file .bash and .py

.bash file

```
while read -r x
do
printf  "%s\n" ${x} "Found"
done < path/to/file.txt
```

.py file

```
print(${x}+"something here")
```

I want to establish some connection between the two file so the variable the bash holds can be used in the .py file

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556555/382051 ? Have a look at this question and the links therein if you need something more advanced than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the Bash variable otherwise it will be local to Bash:

```bsh
export x
```

Now the variable is an environment variable and you can import it within Python like so :

```py
import os
... os.environ['x']
```

As an example

```py
import os
print(os.environ['HOME'])
```

returns

```bsh
/home/username
```